# How can I get custom_array from Brach.io deep-links?

Tags: http, deep-linking, branch.io

I have an e-commerce application and I want to share my item/cart to other users. For sharing, I am using Branch.io for creating deep-links. I am appending some custom data while creating the URL and send it to other users. Otherwise, I will keep the URL in my database for future use. Sometimes I am not able to get the data from the URL once it's created or after some days. As per the [documentation of branch.io](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/deep-linking-api), there is no expiration for the URL. The following API I am using for creating a deep-link:

```
POST /v1/url HTTP/1.1
Host: api2.branch.io
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "branch_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxseaem3d",
    "data": {
        "custom_array": [
            {
                "item_id": "5e96f893264b7869d143f7f2",
                "store_id": "5e7355deb1f5974bbd0bab18",
                "items_group_id": "5e7355deb1f5974bbd0brer18"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "url": "https://jazzly.app.link/YDPMzhg1k7"
}
```

We can able to check the data is available in the URL or not using the following API.

```
GET /v1/url?url=https://jazzly.app.link/YDPMzhg1k7&branch_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxseaem3d 
HTTP/1.1
Host: api2.branch.io
```

By using this API I am getting the following result. Here the custom_array is missing.

```
{
    "data": {
        "+url": "https://jazzly.app.link/YDPMzhg1k7",
        "~creation_source": 0,
        "~id": "801058500452495196",
        "$one_time_use": false,
        "url": "https://jazzly.app.link/YDPMzhg1k7"
    },
    "type": 0
}
```

This issue comes with only some links. Some links are working properly some links are not. Actually it's very helpful for dynamically open the application for IOS and Android. How I can fix this issue? Is there any parameter is missing while I am creating the deep-link URL or is there an expiration time for keeping custom data in the deep-link?

Answer (score 0):

A Branchster here -

Upon checking your link `https://jazzly.app.link/YDPMzhg1k7`, I couldn't find any custom data associated.

To reproduce this we made API requests with your custom data and got the following link - `https://jazzly.app.link/cLX6GEFk07`. Further, we could read the associated link data as well -

[image: Reading Link Data Response]

We would suggest you recheck on the same behaviour and if the issue still persists drop an email to `support@branch.io`

Comment: The issue comes some times only. Not every time. Suppose if we check the link after two-three days, some times the customer array is missing.